# How can I find the status of an workflow execution?

Tags: flyte

For my current project, after I trigger a workflow, I need to check the status of its execution. I am not sure about the exact command. I have tried 'get-workflow' but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, increasing in order of heavy-handedness.

1. You can hit with curl or something the API endpoint directly in [Admin](http://%20https://github.com/lyft/flyteidl/blob/master/protos/flyteidl/service/admin.proto#L233).
2. The Python SDK (flytekit) also ships with a command-line control plane utility called `flyte-cli`.  In the future this may move to another location but it's here for now and you can hit it with [this command](https://github.com/lyft/flytekit/blob/master/flytekit/clis/flyte_cli/main.py#L1470).

```
flyte-cli -p yourproject -d development get-execution -u ex:yourproject:development:2fd90i
```

3. You can also use the [Python class in flytekit](https://github.com/lyft/flytekit/blob/1926b1285591ae941d7fc9bd4c2e4391c5c1b21b/flytekit/common/workflow_execution.py#L103) that represents a workflow execution.

```
In [1]: from flytekit.configuration import set_flyte_config_file

In [2]: set_flyte_config_file('/Users/user/.flyte/config')

In [3]: from flytekit.common.workflow_execution import SdkWorkflowExecution

In [4]: e = SdkWorkflowExecution.fetch('yourproject', 'development', '2fd90i')
```